Covariant derivative of the second fundamental form in a doubly warped product
I am reading Petersen's Riemannian Manifolds (third edition) and came across this assertion:

We wish to compute the curvatures on $(I\times S^p\times S^q , \mathrm{d}r^2+\rho(r)^2 \mathrm{d}s_p^2+\phi(r)^2 \mathrm{d}s_q^2)$.
This time the Hessian looks like
$$ \mathrm{Hess}~r = (\partial_r\rho) \rho ~\mathrm{d}s_p^2 + (\partial_r\phi) \phi ~\mathrm{d}s_q^2 $$
and we see as in the rotationally symmetric case that
$$ \nabla_X \mathrm{I\!I} = 0. $$

Here $\mathrm{d}s_p^2$ denotes the standard metric on $S^p(1)$. I am unable to prove the last assertion.
For additional context, here's how I did the rotationally symmetric case:
The metric on $I\times S^{n-1}$ is given by $g=\mathrm{d}r^2 + \rho^2 ~\mathrm{d}s_{n-1}^2 = \mathrm{d}r^2 + g_r $ which gives $\mathrm{Hess}~ r = \frac{\partial_r \rho}{\rho} g_r $.
Then
$$ \nabla_X \mathrm{I\!I}= \nabla_X (\mathrm{Hess}~ r) = \nabla_X \left(\frac{\partial_r \rho}{\rho} g_r\right) \\
 = \mathrm{D}_X \left(\frac{\partial_r \rho}{\rho}\right)  g_r + \frac{\partial_r \rho}{\rho} \nabla_X g_r =0 $$
The first term vanishes because $\frac{\partial_r \rho}{\rho}$ is a constant function on $S^{n-1}$.
The second term vanishes because $ 0 = \nabla_X g = \nabla_X (\mathrm{d}r^2+g_r) = \nabla_X g_r $. This is the step that I'm unable to generalise to the doubly warped case.
